# Как сделать, чтобы scrollbar прокручивался автоматически в конец textbox'a

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, прокрутка

Программа наподобие чата.С некоторой частотой она считывает информацию с файла на сервере, из-за чего возникает проблема - scrollbar каждый раз прокручивается в начало чата.Помогите решить эту проблему
Отрывок метода:

```
private void enter_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// Считывание с файла
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    string message = " ";
    message = enter_chat.Text;

    if (message != " " && message != "" && message != "  " && message != "   ")
    {    
        List<string> file = DownloadFileFromServer("http://fschat.ucoz.net/fs_chat.txt", "Task").ToList<string>();
        file.Add("element");
        file.Add(nickname);
        file.Add(message);
        file.Add(date.Hour + ":" + date.Minute);
        File.WriteAllLines("fs_chat.txt", file);
        UploadFileToServer("fs_chat.txt", "fschat.ucoz.net/fs_chat.txt");       
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ошибка: пустая строка");
    }
    enter_chat.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

При каждом обновлении выполняйте

```
YourTextBox.AppendText(YourTextBox.SelectedText);
```

Или (Следуя инструкции от [MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.scrolltocaret(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
    RichTextBox1.SelectedText = TextBox1.Text + "\r\n";
    RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```

p.s. Слышал про метод .ScrollToEnd(); , но сам никогда не использовал.

Comment: `ScrollToEnd` - это метод из WPF.